# python-IME-How can i type text to any area of my gnome system?

Tags: python, clipboard, ime

I use an input method called [CangJie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cangjie_input_method).
For example, when I type `a`, I want a window show a character `日`, then I type <kbd>space</kbd>, and the `日` would be input to the text-area where I want to type (e.g. in a text-edit, a browser, or in LibreOffice, ...).

I even think about using system's clipboard to do it, but I don't know how to control clipboard (to past contents) via python.

Who can tell me?